# timing belt replacement for Suzuki New Vitara, APK416D engine

Tags: timing-belt, motor-mounts

I wonder if i could do it in my front yard. Main concerns I guess would be not dropping the engine to the ground and installing the mounting bracket back after job is finished.

[image]

Also, first step is called "Engine Assembly Removal" which itself comprises some 60-70 things to be done, mostly taking the whole front of the car apart (overkill?)

> 25)Support engine and transaxle using jack.
>
> 26)Remove engine right mounting bracket bolt (1), nuts (2) and left
> mounting bracket bolt (3) and nuts (4).

Can some wood blocks be used instead ? Biggest worry - mounting bracket nuts and bolts won't align after the job.

Comment: Please edit the first question with the information. There is no reason to create another question for the same thing.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Should I ? That one already received an answer (your comment). I don't find the two question to be identical, only related.

Comment: My comment is not an answer.